# Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'. Tensorflow v 2.11.0. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

`print(tf.__version__)` doesn't work. Same thing with `print(tf.version)`, `print(tf.version.VERSION)`, `print(tf.VERSION)`

I am using Windows 10 x64. Python v 3.10.7.

I don't want to reinstall to the old version of Tensorflow 1.14

`pip list`:

[image]

If I write simply `print(tf)` , then it gives out this:
[image]

Comment: Show us this output `print(tf.__file__)`

Comment: It prints: None.
What does it mean?

Comment: Well, that's unusual.  I hoped it would print out the full path to the tensorflow module, which in turn might tell us if you were accidentally importing the wrong thing.  Try this instead: `print(dir(tf))`

Comment: @JohnGordon I've been having the same problem. Output is: ['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Comment: I am having the same problem with tensorflow 2.12.0 I just upgraded to so that I can load audio dataset from a directory. I get ['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__'] Any resolution for this issue?

Comment: After installing tensorflow in a virtual environment my problem went away. I think there are random issues with tensorflow when installed in a physical environment which seem to go away after moving to a virual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try again as I replicated the same above code in mentioned version of `Python 3.10` and `TensorFlow 2.11` in conda environment, which shows the expected result as mentioned below:

[image]

Comment: same result as before I'm afraid, following your nice script. I'll try again after 2,10 to  2.11

Answer (score 0):

I think there are random issues with tensorflow like this at times when installed in a physical environment which seem to go away after moving to a virual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you downgrade to `TensorFlow==2.10` it should fix the issue. `__version__` attribute was removed from `2.11`

Answer (score 0):

I create a new virtual environment using anaconda, and reinstalled tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow==2.11.0`. Everything is ok afterwards.

I have tried @JohnGordon's testing methods, all outputs were fine.